# How to use trained neural network as function using MATLAB coder?

Tags: c++, matlab, neural-network, matlab-coder

I've trained a simple neural network that just multiply 4 numbers and gives 1 number as an output.

```
  ( output(x0) = in1(x0)*in2(x0)*in3(x0) *in4(x0)).
```

or
description:
[image: description]

My neural net has 4 inputs, and 1 output, [10 10] is the hidden layer. I used 'genFunction' to generate a .m file out of network.then I used MATLAB coder to generate C++ function. I generate the code with following input types:
input types:
[image: input types]

My problem is when I test the C++ code it only gives the 2 first samples for the output.

I store my entries in a std:: vector which has size of 400 (each input size is 100)

I've done the following so far (no desirable output though):

```
 std::vector<double> Multiplier(std::vector<double>& input)
 {
   double* X_data = new double[input.size()];
   X_data = vec2ar(input);
   int X_size[2];
   X_size[0] = 4;
   X_size[1] = 100;
   double* Y_data = new double[input.size()];
   int Y_size[100];
```

While the original was:

```
void multiplier(const double X_data[], const int X_size[2], double Y_data[], int
Y_size[2])
{
 double Xp1_data[800];
 int Xp1_size[2];
 int j;
 double a1_data[2000];
 int coffset;
 int a1_size[2];
 int boffset;
 double tmp_data[2000];
 int k;
 double b_a1_data[2000];
```

And for getting the output:

```
std::vector<double> output;
output = ar2vec(Y_data);
return output;
```

All I want is we have 4 vectors and give them to this function simply just multiply corresponding samples as shown in 'description' (in my case we have 4 vectors of size 100, and we expect an output with size 100).

And for ar2vec and vec2ar functions:

```
std::vector<double> ar2vec(double arr[])
{
std::vector<double> vec;
copy(&arr[0], &arr[100], std::back_inserter(vec));
return vec;
}

double* vec2ar(std::vector<double> vec)
{
double * arr = new double[vec.size()];
copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), arr);
return arr;
}
```

How to fix my problem?

Comment: Some observations:
 (1) `Y_size` should have 2 elements not 100 as shown in the declaration: `int Y_size[100];`. Probably not the cause of unexpected results

 (2) By default the generated code stores data in column major order. Data in C is typically row major. Could it be that you need to transpose the data?
 
 (3) Have you made sure to call the generated `_initialize` function before calling 
 our generated code?

 (4) Consider enabling the "Generate run-time error checks" setting (`cfg.RuntimeChecks = 1`) in the Debugging pane to see if there are runtime errors reported.

Comment: @RyanLivingston i think the source of my problem is (2) . functions i defined above(vec2ar, ar2vec) should satisfy this transformation.right?

Comment: Correct, those functions would need to perform the transpositions. MATLAB Coder added a row major option in R2018a. I'll write up an answer with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

By default, MATLAB Coder generates code which stores matrices and ND arrays in column major order. The typical layout in C and C++ is row major order. To ensure correct behavior, the data must be converted from row major to column major before invoking the generated code and then back to row major to use the output.

Starting in MATLAB R2018a, MATLAB Coder provides the option to generate row major code. Enabling this setting will relieve you of the need to convert data majority if your code already stores the data in row major order. The [release notes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/release-notes.html?rntext=row-major&startrelease=R2015aSP1&endrelease=R2018b&groupby=release&sortby=descending&searchHighlight=row-major) describe this and the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2018a/coder/array-layout.html) has a section describing these options with MATLAB Coder.